# Почему не срабатывают переход по метке из внутреннего цикла на внешний?

Tags: javascript

Не подскажете, в чем ошибка кода ниже?

Ошибок в консоль не выводится, но и перехода на внешний цикл по метке `outer` не происходит.

```js
let fruits = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Слива", "Груша", "Мандарин", "Лимон", "Дыня", "Гранат"];
        
let index;
        
let indx;
        
let a;
        
outer: for(;;) {
  for (indx = 0; indx < fruits.length; indx++) {
    if (indx === indx[5]) {
      break outer;
    }
    console.log(fruits[indx]);
  }
  console.log("a");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indx` - число. нельзя использовать `indx === indx[5]` потому что `indx[5]` не определён

```js
let fruits = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Слива", "Груша", "Мандарин", "Лимон", "Дыня", "Гранат"];
        
outer: for(;;) {
  console.log("->");
  for (let indx = 0, len = fruits.length; indx < len; indx++) {
    if (indx === 5) {
      break outer;
    }
    console.log(fruits[indx]);
  }
}
console.log(".");
```